# Open Event Viewer from Setup

Tags: windows-10, setup, event-viewer

I am currently trying to install Windows 10. Unfortunately the setup states it was unable to create a partition on my SSD. Details should be in the Setup Log. To view this I presumably need the Event Viewer.

My question is, how do I open the Event Viewer without a running Windows? I can't find any button or icon or other kind of GUI element and the command prompt tells me

> 'eventvwr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

How do I open the Event Viewer or is there another way to show the setup log?

Comment: As the SSD just gave it's last breath the problem is at least postponed until the replacement one arrives in the mail. Still curious though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

```
eventvwr.msc /s
```

or - with the full path -

```
c:\Windows\system32\eventvwr.msc /s
```

Comment: This also leads to `'eventvwr.msc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I expanded my answer - use the second command (as you probably don't have it in your PATH environment variable).

Comment: There are 3 local disks shown by wmic. One is called C, but has no volume name and I cannot cd there. Second is D, DVD I'm trying to install from, I can not cd there either. And third X, called Boot. I can cd there but it doesn't contain the eventvwr. If I try your second line of code all I get is `The system cannot find the path specified` when tried with C or D and the above error when tried with X.